# Target pseudo class using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, pseudo-class

I have the following two styles in a stylesheet that I do not have access to:

```
a:link {
  font-size: 150%;
}

a:hover {
  font-size: 150%;
}
```

Using jQuery, how can I change the font-size here to 100% for both a:link and a:hover.

Comment: Why not just add another stylesheet (or `<style>` block) after this one with the new rules?

Comment: Good point but I guess I was more after a jQuery solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@Phil is correct in his comment above, a rule can be added directly. A `<style/>` element can be appended at runtime to `<head/>` which will trigger a page re-render (?) and the new styles will be applied! [From the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ovfiddle/hxADc/):

```
$('head').append('<style type="text/css">a:hover{color:red !important;}</style>');
```

For some reason the `head` selector doesn't look right to me but hey, it works! Hover over the link in 5 seconds time (for argument's sake) and it'll be styled.

Comment: You could also apply an id to the inserted style block, should you want to remove it later.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want it by jQuery only you can use the following code (just make sure you write this script after you have imported the above css from remote file)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a').on('hover',function(){
        $(this).css({'font-size':'100%'});
    }).css({'font-size':'100%'});    
});​
```

Although you can also do it by adding a simple style to your page and appending `!important` to the rules

```
<style type="text/css">
a:link {
  font-size: 100% !important;
}

a:hover {
  font-size: 100% !important;
}
</style>
```

[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/lonewolfs/S48SG/)

Comment: You don't need the `!important` overrides. The selector specificity is the same so the latter rules will apply. Also, your JS does not solve the `a:link` problem (assuming `a:visited` are styled differently)

Comment: @Phil The question was specific to link and hover effects using jQuery else we can always add a new style to override those :)